# six foot avocado tree (indoor)

Tags: trees, indoors, avocado

I have been given an avocado tree that is six feet tall. It looks more like a big bushy vine, and was never staked. Need to trim it and need to know how far back I can cut it safely.

Comment: Upload a good photo of the plant

Comment: It is common to prune main trunk on an avocado (so it would be more bushy). But "vine" tell me that it doesn't have enough sun. How much sun does it get?